SHA-1 with google API
I'm trying to create an Android project and I'm having trouble finishing it due to an issue. Currently, within the project, I'm using Google authentication to concurrently utilize the Google Fit service, which I registered through the Firebase website. To achieve this, I had to enter the SHA1 and project name. Now, I want to program a barcode scanner, and I came up with the idea of creating it using Google Vision. However, when I try to create the project via the website, it tells me that the SHA1/project name is already taken, which is true because I used it to use Google Fit/login. What should I do? I want to use both Google services, and I don't understand why it's a problem that it's the same project.
I tried deliting SHA1 from firebase, and that didnt help..

First, you wont be able to use Google Fit as the platform is now deprecated and no new Fit API requests will be provisioned starting May 1st. Go out and check Health Connect, their replacement platform.
As for the SHA1 issue, I'd reach out to Google cloud support and check if they can assist you with your issue. T
